# No upgrade options since booting via CD Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: upgrade

I have bootable cd of Ubuntu 11.10

But, when I inserted it on my pc, there is no upgrade option from ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04.

Can you help me regarding this??

Thanks.

Comment: why are you shouting?

Comment: Can you please edit the question, so that it use lower case letters.

Comment: Why's everything upper case ?

Comment: HI IT WOULD BE NICE IF YOU WOULD NOT USE CAPSLOCK.

Comment: Can there be an upgrade option to 12.04 in Ubuntu 11.10 CD? If you want to upgrade to 12.04, you need 12.04 CD.

Answer (score 3):

If your CD is 11.10 you can use it to update from an earlier version (e.g., 11.04).

To upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 you need a 12.04 installation CD.